# ExtJS 4 How to get Form value as Integer

Tags: json, forms, extjs4, int

I'm using  Ext.JSON.encode(this.getUserForm().getForm().getValues()) to encode my form values in Json fomat.

Here is the probleme : All values are encoded as string, even integer values.

```
{
  "userId":"15",
  "username":"Albert",
  "firstName":"Albert",
  "lastName":"Einstein"
}
```

the user id a **HiddenFiled**

How to make my user ID field encoded as Integer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hidden field is " typeless" so it doesn't condition or convert its value. You have two main options:

1. Extend the hidden field to implement getValue method that would return integers instead of strings
2. Use params instead of hidden fields to send id data to the server

Answer (score 0):

try

```
this.getUserForm().getForm().getFieldValues()
```

getValues returns only String values for submission

I cant understand the question at first, your number is in "_" may be you need some javascript

```
isNaN('fds5sdf') returns true
 isNaN('15')  returns false
```

so if isNaN function return false you have to parts to Int, parseInt('15');

at first try getFieldValues() if your item in form is xtype: 'numberfield' getFieldValues reurns integer value...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Saki.I decided to go for the first option.

```
Ext.define('MA.view.custom.HField', {
extend: 'Ext.form.field.Hidden',
xtype: 'hfield',

getValue: function () {
      var value;
      var v = this.getSubmitValue();
      value = parseInt(v);
      return value;
 }
```

});